# MYSQL/SQL : How can i do 2 query into 1

Tags: mysql, sql

i really need your help because i'm pretty limited in SQL.

I have a table "beats", who list all my beats music and an other table "rating" who list the rate of a beat by user.

BEATS TABLES : https://i.stack.imgur.com/4z6wA.jpg
RATING TABLE : https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLM18.jpg

I need to get the total rate by beats in my beats select...
So i have a beats query, i have a rating query to get the total of rate (SELECT sum(rate) as total_rate FROM rating WHERE beat_id = x) but how combine them ?

Thank's a lot,

Comment: Share the table schemas in question @Brayan233. Image is not clear.

Comment: Share the data structure of the tables in an identical way and format. The question should present the information clearly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select your beats and get the rating in a subquery:

```
select
  b.*,
  (select sum(rate) from rating r where beat_id = b.id) as total_rate
from beats b;
```

That is simplest solution. You can get the same with a join of course:

```
select
  b.*,
  r.total_rate
from beats b
left join
(
  select beat_id, sum(rate) as total_rate
  from rating 
  group by beat_id
) r on r.beat_id  = b.id;
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help !

Answer (score 0):

This will help in SQL.

```
SELECT sum(r.rate) as total_rate 
FROM rating r 
INNER JOIN Beats B ON B.Rate = r.Id
WHERE B.beat_id ='x'
```

Comment: It's doesn't help me, cause i need to select from the beat table.
Exemple : I have 3 users who rated a beat (user1,2,3); So in the rate table i have 3 records ( user_id : 1 , beat_id : 57 , rate:3), ( user_id : 2 , beat_id : 57 , rate:6), ( user_id : 3 , beat_id : 57 , rate:3), so now how can i display the total of rate for the beat 57 (rate 12)  in my beats select?